# increase number in string

Tags: c++, stdstring, leveldb

I have to save an increasing ID as key into a levelDB database. So what I get (and what I have to give to levelDB) is a string.

**Question**: Is there an elegant way to increase a number saved in a string?

Example:

```
std::string key = "123";
[..fancy code snipped to increase key by 1..]
std::cout << key << std::endl;  // yields 124
```

Cheers!

PS: Would prefer to stay with standard compilation, i.e. no C++11.

Comment: are you sure the value is not 124?

Comment: @izomorphius: typo.. thanks .. it's from 123 to 124

Comment: So your key is actually 123, not your value? What happens with your old key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
std::string key = "123";
std::istringstream in(key);
int int_key;
in >> int_key;
int_key++;
std::ostringstream out;
out << int_key;
key = out.str();
std::cout << key << std::endl;
```

You can also do it using c style casting:

```
std::string key = "123";
int int_key = atoi(key.c_str());
int_key++;
char key_char[20];
itoa(int_key, key_char, 10);
key = key_char;
cout << key << endl;
```

Comment: could it be that itoa is not standard c++ .. looks like it is not supported by g++

Comment: hmmm I am 99% sure it is supported by g++. Try including cstdlib

Comment: I am sorry - it seems that itoa is not a standrard function and may not be supported by your compiler. The code ran successfully on my compiler, though. Use this code instead the itoa call: `sprintf(key_char, "%d", int_key)`

Comment: I used your first example. Cheers and +1

Answer (score 2):

You could always write a small routine to do base 10 arithmetic, but the simplest solution is usually to keep the number as an `int` (or some other integral type), and convert that into a string as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::string key = "123";
std::stringstream out;
out << (atoi(key.c_str()) + 1);
key = out.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
istringstream iss(key);
int ikey;
iss >> ikey;
ostringstream oss;
oss << (ikey+1);
key = oss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's true that leveldb does take in strings and it can return a string, **but** the `Slice` structure also has a constructor with an opaque array of data:

```
// Create a slice that refers to data[0,n-1].
Slice(const char* data, size_t n)
```

When you get a key `Slice` you still have a `char*` as the data, so you don't really have to bother with the strings:

```
// Return a pointer to the beginning of the referenced data
const char* data() const { return data_; }
```

If your entire goal is to have a an integer as the key, then just convert your integer to a char* and store it in `leveldb`, like so:

```
int oldKey = 123;
char key[8];
memset(key, 0, 8);

*(int*)(&key) = oldKey;
*(int*)(&key) += 1;

// key is now 124

// want to put it back in a slice? 
Slice s(key, sizeof(int));
```

No need for pesky and expensive strings...

Comment: error: cast from 'char*’ to ‘int’ loses precision :( (in `key = (char*)(((int)key)+1);`)

Comment: @ezdazuzena I'm not getting the error, here is a gcc-4.3.4 compiled version: http://ideone.com/W3NQ2 I've also compiled the same code in VS 2010 (both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms). How are you compiling it?

Comment: gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

Comment: Hmmm... OK, I've modified the code, see if it works now... I think it shouldn't be happening anymore.